# ¿Es posible redimensionar un vector?

Tags: java

Existe alguna manera de redimensionar un vector en Java? Por ejemplo como

```
int vector[5] = {0};
```

Y le ingreso datos, y si quiero que guarde más números aumentarle el tamaño al vector sin que pierda los datos que ya contiene

Comment: No,en tal caso declaras otro o usas un arrayList

Comment: En Java, un array como el que nos muestras se define como [*un objeto que contiene un **número fijo de valores** de un solo tipo*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html), por tanto, una vez creado con una dimensión específica, no puedes cambiarla por otra. Como dice @Dramaturgo, si quieres un array dinámico, deberás usar `ArrayList`

Answer (score 2):

Sí se puede redimensionar un [**Vector**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html).

**Un [**Vector**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html) es similar a un [**Array**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html), la diferencia se encuentra en que un [Vector](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html) crece automáticamente cuando alcanza la dimensión inicial máxima**, por ejemplo:

```
Vector<Integer> vector = new Vector<>(5);

vector.add(1);
vector.add(2);
vector.add(3);
vector.add(4);
vector.add(5);
vector.add(6);        
vector.add(7);
vector.add(8);
vector.add(9);
vector.add(10);

System.out.println(vector);
```

salida:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

en cambio, un [**Array**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) no se puede re dimensionar, una vez creado este no puede ser dimensionado nuevamente.

```
int vector[] = new int[5];
vector[0] = 1;
vector[1] = 2;
vector[2] = 3;
vector[3] = 4;
vector[4] = 5;
//vector[5] = 6; //*agregar un sexto elemento marcaría error!.
```

Comment: Entonces la pregunta tiene un problema de nombres ;)

Comment: Creo que estás mezclando las cosas. Los términos _matriz_, _array_, _arreglo_ y _vector_ se refieren al mismo concepto ["una zona de almacenamiento contiguo (...) de elementos del mismo tipo"](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_(inform%C3%A1tica)). Ahora bien, la clase [Vector](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Vector.html) es un TDA que implementa una lista secuencial basada en un arreglo y fue, digámoslo así, la primera versión del [ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ArrayList.html).

Comment: Aunque algunos TDAs disponibles en la biblioteca estándar del lenguaje tomen su nombre (o parte de este) de los términos con los que nos referimos a los arreglos no podemos confundir una cosa con la otra.

Por lo tanto creo que esta respuesta está completamente equivocada.